# Polars is much slower than DuckDB in conditional join + groupby/agg context

Tags: python, python-polars, duckdb

For the following example, where it involves a self conditional join and a subsequent groupby/aggregate operation. It turned out that in such case, `DuckDB` gives much better performance than `Polars` (~10x on a 32-core machine).

My questions are:

1. What could be the potential reason(s) for the slowness (relative to `DuckDB`) of `Polars`?
2. Am I missing some other faster ways of doing the same thing in `Polars`?

```
import time

import duckdb
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

## example dataframe
rng = np.random.default_rng(1)

nrows = 5_000_000
df = pl.DataFrame(
    dict(
        id=rng.integers(1, 1_000, nrows),
        id2=rng.integers(1, 10, nrows),
        id3=rng.integers(1, 500, nrows),
        value=rng.normal(0, 1, nrows),
    )
)

## polars
start = time.perf_counter()
res = (
    df.lazy()
    .join(df.lazy(), on=["id", "id2"], how="left")
    .filter(
        (pl.col("id3") > pl.col("id3_right"))
        & (pl.col("id3") - pl.col("id3_right") < 30)
    )
    .groupby(["id2", "id3", "id3_right"])
    .agg(pl.corr("value", "value_right"))
    .collect(streaming=True)
)
time.perf_counter() - start
# 120.93155245436355

## duckdb
start = time.perf_counter()
res2 = (
    duckdb.sql(
        """
        SELECT df.*, df2.id3 as id3_right, df2.value as value_right
        FROM df JOIN df as df2
        ON (df.id = df2.id
        AND df.id2 = df2.id2
        AND df.id3 > df2.id3
        AND df.id3 - df2.id3 < 30)
        """
    )
    .aggregate(
        "id2, id3, id3_right, corr(value, value_right) as value",
        "id2, id3, id3_right",
    )
    .pl()
)
time.perf_counter() - start
# 18.472263277042657
```

Comment: It's also to do with the fact that the DuckDb version performs a range join. https://duckdb.org/2022/05/27/iejoin.html

Comment: [v0.18.3](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/releases/tag/py-0.18.3) was just released. There is now a `1.8x` difference compared to a `15x` difference using `v0.18.2` when I test this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### EDIT: 2023-7-18

The latest polars release has brought the difference down from 15x to 2x.

```
polars v0.18.2  1125
polars v0.18.3  140
duckdb 0.8.2-dev1   75
```

## Original answer

### Streaming engine

The streaming API isn't as optimized yet. Polars is a younger project than DuckDB and we haven't got as many paid developers on the project.

So give us time. Next release `0.18.3` will land a PR that can make a streaming groupby over 3.5x faster https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/9346.

That just shows how much we still have on the table on the streaming engine. That same optimization we still have to do for streaming joins.

In short. Our streaming engine is in alpha stage. It is work in progress.

### Different algorithm

Other that that, the duckdb query might also be using non-equi joins under the hood which we don't have yet in polars, so this query might not be as optimal for polars.

Answer (score 2):

While DuckDB does have several non-equi-joins, the planner currently assumes that all equality predicates are more selective than inequalities an just generates a hash join here:

```sql
D EXPLAIN SELECT id2, id3, id3_right, corr(value, value_right) as value
> FROM (
>     SELECT df.*, df2.id3 as id3_right, df2.value as value_right
>     FROM df JOIN df as df2
>         ON (df.id = df2.id
>         AND df.id2 = df2.id2
>         AND df.id3 > df2.id3
>         AND df.id3 - df2.id3 < 30)
>     ) tbl
> GROUP BY ALL
> ;

┌─────────────────────────────┐
│┌───────────────────────────┐│
││       Physical Plan       ││
│└───────────────────────────┘│
└─────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────────────────┐                             
│       HASH_GROUP_BY       │                             
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │                             
│             #0            │                             
│             #1            │                             
│             #2            │                             
│        corr(#3, #4)       │                             
└─────────────┬─────────────┘                                                          
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐                             
│         PROJECTION        │                             
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │                             
│            id2            │                             
│            id3            │                             
│         id3_right         │                             
│           value           │                             
│        value_right        │                             
└─────────────┬─────────────┘                                                          
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐                             
│         PROJECTION        │                             
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │                             
│             #1            │                             
│             #2            │                             
│             #3            │                             
│             #4            │                             
│             #5            │                             
└─────────────┬─────────────┘                                                          
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐                             
│           FILTER          │                             
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │                             
│     ((id3 - id3) < 30)    │                             
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │                             
│      EC: 24727992087      │                             
└─────────────┬─────────────┘                                                          
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐                             
│         HASH_JOIN         │                             
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │                             
│           INNER           │                             
│          id = id          │                             
│         id2 = id2         ├──────────────┐              
│         id3 > id3         │              │              
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │              │              
│      EC: 24727992087      │              │              
│     Cost: 24727992087     │              │              
└─────────────┬─────────────┘              │                                           
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
│         SEQ_SCAN          ││         SEQ_SCAN          │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   ││   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
│             df            ││             df            │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   ││   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
│             id            ││             id            │
│            id2            ││            id2            │
│            id3            ││            id3            │
│           value           ││           value           │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   ││   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
│        EC: 5000000        ││        EC: 5000000        │
└───────────────────────────┘└───────────────────────────┘
```

We plan to address this in a future release.

Note also that the IEJoin algorithm requires two inequalities and the query only has one. Single inequalities could be handled by the PieceWiseMergeJoin operator, but PWMJ does not currently handle simple equalities (the logic would just have to be extended to handle `NULL`s correctly).

Comment: Does it mean that the kind of operations in my example could be potentially faster in future?

Comment: Quite possibly. I did a little test forcing it to use IEJoin (after changing the last predicate to have one field on each side...) and it was 2-3x faster.

Comment: With a proper benchmark using a new pragma, the gain is more like 6x.

Comment: How can I access to this faster version?

Comment: It would be a prerelease (`pip install duckdb --pre --upgrade`) but it is still in code review.